# Difference in between Covariance and Correlation Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, correlation, covariance

In Matlab, I have created a matrix A with size `(244x2014723)` 
and a matrix B with size `(244x1)`

I was able to calculate the correlation matrix using `corr(A,B)` which yielded in a matrix of size `2014723x1`. So, every column of matrix A correlates with matrix B and gives one row value in the matrix of size `2014723x1`.

My question is when I ask for a covariance matrix using `cov(A,B)`, I get an error saying A and B should be of same sizes. Why do I get this error? How is the method to find `corr(A,B)` any different from `cov(A,B)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty clear if you read the documentation:

[`cov`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cov.html):

> If A and B are matrices of observations, cov(A,B) treats A and B as vectors and is equivalent to cov(A(:),B(:)). A and B must have equal size.

[`corr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/corr.html)

> corr(X,Y) returns a p1-by-p2 matrix containing the pairwise correlation coefficient between each pair of columns in the n-by-p1 and n-by-p2 matrices X and Y.
>
> The difference between corr(X,Y) and the MATLAB® function corrcoef(X,Y) is that corrcoef(X,Y) returns a matrix of correlation coefficients for the two column vectors X and Y. If X and Y are not column vectors, corrcoef(X,Y) converts them to column vectors.

One way you could get the covariances of your vector with each column of you matrix is to use a loop. Another way (might be in-efficient depending on the size) is

```
C = cov([B,A])
```

and then look at the first row (or column) or `C`.

Answer (score 0):

See [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cov.html?refresh=true)

In the more about section, the equation describing how cov is computed for cov(A,B) makes it clear why they need to be the same size. The summation is over only one variable which enumerates the elements of A,B.